# Alternator whine fix for aftermarket stereo

Tags: electrical, audio, electronics

I bought a Dual MPR420 as a cheap replacement for my 22 year old Toyota Camry that I keep around as a utility car. I used the right Metra harness, spliced using heat shrink butt connectors and everything worked without a hitch EXCEPT for the terrible alternator whine. I checked the grounds and they seemed OK. A few ferrite beads and an active power filter later, the alternator whine is pretty much gone while the unit is not bolted in. The moment I bolt the until in, the alternator whine becomes terrible (this was true before and after the filter was installed).

I took a piece of wire and connected the bracket to the bolt hole and indeed confirmed that the casing and bracket were what was causing the ground loop. I also disconnected the ground on the harness and connected it to the bolt hole and voila, the bolt hole could serve as the negative terminal, confirming that it is indeed a ground.

What are my safe options here? My gut reaction would be to connector one of the brackets to the common ground on the harness, thus grounding the unit's chassis and theoretically eliminating the whine entirely. Why did the factory unit not have this issue?

Comment: The classic solution on alternators was a capacitor on the alternator output. Not sure why you want to know what the manufacturer did...

Comment: "Why did the factory unit not have this issue?" Because they did not use the chassis for ground.